# bash: sed to extract all lines from string until different string

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following text `input.txt` file

```
abc xyz 123
  this is text
  i dont need
abc def 123
  this is text
  i want to keep
and this also
{
contains
}
these lines

 xyz
xyz

abc def ppp
  this is also text
  i want to keep
abc fff
  this is text
  i dont need
```

I want to keep only the text where the section starts with `abc def` like below

```
abc def 123
  this is text
  i want to keep
and this also
{
contains
}
these lines

 xyz
xyz

abc def ppp
  this is also text
  i want to keep
```

I have the command `sed -n "/^abc def/,/^abc fff/p" input.txt` and got this:

```
abc def 123
  this is text
  i want to keep
and this also
abc def ppp
  this is also text
  i want to keep
abc fff
```

But i got 2 problems:

- it grabs the line `abc fff`
- the marker to stop is not necessary `abc fff`, it can be `abc fgh`

Edit: I would like to remove the files from the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you tagged your question with `sed`, following `gnu-awk` should be a good tool to get the job done:

```bash
awk -v RS='abc ' '$1 == "def" {print RT $0}' input.txt

abc def 123
  this is text
  i want to keep
and this also
{
contains
}
these lines

 xyz
xyz


abc def ppp
  this is also text
  i want to keep
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/77NFFc)

---

To store output in another file, use:

```bash
awk -v RS='abc ' '$1 == "def" {print RT $0 > "output"}' input.txt
```

---

To remove all matched text use:

```bash
awk -v RS='abc ' '$1 != "def" {ORS=RT; print $0 > "removed"}' input.txt
```

Comment: @xavi: Did you get a chance to test this? I have shown generated output in my answer and added an online demo.

Comment: yes it works well. thanks for the simple command.
i am tying to remove these extracted lines from the input file as well which is why i looked at sed at the beginning

Comment: I have updated answer with a command to remove matched text that has `abc def`

Comment: yes. will do for next time.

Comment: the extract and remove works perfectly!. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/^\S/{:a;x;/\S/{/^abc def|^\S[^\n]*$/p};$!b;x;/^\S/p;b};H;$ba' file
```

In essence, print a stanza (an unindented line followed by zero or more indented lines) if it begins `abc def` or is a single line.

Turn off implicit printing and turn on extended regexp `-nE`.

If the current line is the first (or only) line of a stanza, switch to the hold space.

If the hold space is not empty and begins `abc def` or is the only line of a stanza, print it.

If this is not the last line, break and the current line becomes the hold space.

Otherwise, this must be the last line of the file and if it is the first line of stanza print it.

All other lines are appended to the hold space and if it happens to be the last line of the file, the program flow jumps back up and treats it as if the first line of a stanza has been found.

---

As the input has changed and I believe the delimiter for a stanza is any line beginning `abc` , a simpler solution:

```
sed -nE '/^abc def/{:a;p;n;/^abc /!ba;s/^/\n/;D}' file
```

Print any stanza that begins `abc def` until another stanza beginning `abc` , then prepend a newline and invoke the `D` command, which preserves the current pattern space having removed up and including the first newline.

Comment: i have updated the input file as it would not work if the following line of "abc def" does not start with a space. I tried different variations from your sed but i could not get it working.

Comment: thanks. it does work to get these lines into a new file but i am also trying to remove these lines from the original file. i am trying with /d but not sure where to put it in.

Comment: @xavi if you want to amend the file input, use the `-i` option see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
/^abc/{
  if(found && val){
    print val
  }
  found=val=""
}
/^abc def$/{
  found=1
}
found{
  val=(val?val ORS:"") $0
}
END{
  if(found && val){
    print val
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
/^abc/{                      ##Checking condition if line starts from abc then do following.
  if(found && val){          ##Checking if found is SET and val is SET then do following.
    print val                ##Printing val here.
  }
  found=val=""               ##Nullifying found and val here.
}
/^abc def$/{                 ##Checking if line starts from abc def then do following.
  found=1                    ##Setting found to 1 here.
}
found{                       ##Checking if found it SET then do following.
  val=(val?val ORS:"") $0    ##Creating val where keeping current line and keep appending it with new line.
}
END{                         ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  if(found && val){          ##Checking if found is SET and val is SET then do following.
    print val                ##Printing val here.
  }
}
'   Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thank you. it does work well for my input file. i forgot to mention i would like to remove these lines from the input file

Comment: @xavi, change from `Input_file` TO `Input_file  > temp && mv temp Input_file` to save output into Input_file itself, try it once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @xavi, Could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you? Thank you.

Comment: yes it extracts the files but does not delete from the input file

Comment: @xavi, have you changed `Input_file  > temp && mv temp Input_file` as mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @xavi, good to hear that it worked for you. You could upvote all helpful answers also upvoting is different from accepting answer cheers